# Button invisibility in one list item is leading to invisibility of buttons of other list items at the spaces of 5,10,15,20 and so on from that item

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-listview

I am working on my project and I have one list view activity which shows me the list of some restaurants that are coming from the database. Each list view item has a button which when pressed adds that respective restaurant on another list on the cloud and disappears. So, this is how it is supposed to work but when I press the button to add that list item on the cloud, buttons of other list items which are at the spaces of 5,10,15,20,... and so on from that list item, also disappear along with that button which I pressed, which is not supposed to happen. I am attaching the code of that activity here and the logic of that item button is implemented in 
**add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {....})** 
at the very end of this code.

```
public class Restaurants_List extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<PLan_List_Data> places;
ListView lv;
String budget, radius;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.plan_list);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Check if Internet present
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    if (!isInternetPresent) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    this.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Bundle bun= getIntent().getExtras();

    budget = bun.getString("budget");
    radius = bun.getString("radius");
    places = new ArrayList<PLan_List_Data>();
    placesList();


}



void populate()
{

    Myadaptee adap = new Myadaptee(this, places);
    setListAdapter(adap);

}

private void placesList() {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("BudgetDatabase");
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> pl_list, ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // If there are results, update the list of posts
                // and notify the adapter
                places.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < pl_list.size(); i++) {


                        PLan_List_Data myObject = new PLan_List_Data();
                        ParseObject object = pl_list.get(i);
                        if(Integer.valueOf(budget)>Integer.valueOf((String) object.get("Budgetnew")))
                        {

                            myObject.id = object.getObjectId();
                            myObject.name = (String) object.get("Name");
                            myObject.address = (String) object.get("Address");
                            myObject.phone = (String) object.get("Phone");
                            myObject.distance = (String) object.get("Distance");
                            myObject.budget = (String) object.get("Budgetnew");
                            places.add(myObject);
                        }
                }

                populate();


            } else {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
private void loadLoginView() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Parse_login.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case (android.R.id.home):
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.action_logout):
            {
            //ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            ParseUser.logOut();
            loadLoginView();
            break;
            }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}

class Myadaptee extends BaseAdapter{
ArrayList<PLan_List_Data> places;
Context con;
//LayoutInflater inflater;
public Myadaptee(Context c, ArrayList<PLan_List_Data> places){
    this.con=c;
    this.places=places;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return places.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return places.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;
    if( row == null ){
        //We must create a View:
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(con.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurants_list_item
                , parent, false);
    }
    //Here we can do changes to the convertView, such as set a text on a TextView 
    //or an image on an ImageView.

    final TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mytitle);
    final TextView addr = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myaddr);
    final TextView ph = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.myph);
    final TextView dist = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mydist);
    final Button add = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button remove = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    title.setText(places.get(position).name);
    addr.setText(places.get(position).address);
    ph.setText(places.get(position).phone);
    dist.setText(places.get(position).distance + "\nBudget: "+places.get(position).budget);

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("DataBase");
            testObject.put("Name", title.getText().toString());
            testObject.put("Address", addr.getText().toString());
            testObject.put("Phone", ph.getText().toString());
            testObject.put("Distance", dist.getText().toString());
            testObject.saveInBackground();
            Toast.makeText(con, "Successfully Added" ,
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            add.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    return row;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the view `INVISIBLE` in your `OnClickListener`. You never again make it visible.

In `getView()`, you need to determine whether or not the row for this `position` should have an `INVISIBLE` view or not, and call `setVisbiility(View.VISIBLE)` or `setVisbiility(View.INVISIBLE)`, just like you call `setText()` on the `TextView` widgets to update their contents.

IOW, the question of whether or not `add` should be visible is just as much of your data model as is the text in the `TextViews`. Just as you update the `TextView` text, so you must update the `add` visibility.

Comment: Okay, so if I update the visibility of `add` as `VISIBLE` in `getView()` then it sets the visibility of that item to `VISIBLE` again. But I want the visibility of `add` to be `GONE` forever for that item only so that it doesn't let user add it multiple times to the list.

Comment: @ManishKumar: Then you need to track that information, noting what positions should be affected. In `getView()`, set the visibility to be `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE`, or `GONE` **every time**, for the current `position`.

Comment: This would be very tedious work to keep track of every list item's button every time. Is there anyway that after pressing the button the list item of `ArrayList` gets deleted and it won't affect the other items? Since I am new to Java, I don't know much.

Comment: @ManishKumar: "This would be very tedious work to keep track of every list item's button every time" -- tracking it in a `SparseBooleanArray`, or even a simple `ArrayList<Boolean>`, should take about five lines of code (one to initialize the array, one to update it when the button is clicked, and three to update the `Button` in `getView` based on the value in the array).